# PostgreSQL avoid nested aggregate functions

Tags: postgresql

```
    SELECT
        p.id AS id,
        json_agg((SELECT x FROM (SELECT 
            c.id, 
            c.name, 
            json_agg((SELECT y FROM (SELECT s.id, s.name) y)) AS js2
            ) x)) AS js1
    FROM p
    INNER JOIN s ON s.id = p.s_id
    INNER JOIN c ON c.s_id = p.s_id
    INNER JOIN cc ON c.id = cc.c_id AND p.c_id = cc.c_id
    GROUP BY p.c_id;
```

I want to aggregate my sql like this, but psql doesn't let me to do js2.

> ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot be nested json_agg((SELECT y FROM (SELECT s.id, ...

How can I avoid this?

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Do not post code or additional information in comments

Comment: You can use rextester. See an example in: http://rextester.com/RTZWK4070

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the json_agg in js2 to row_to_json

```
 SELECT
        p.id AS id,
        json_agg((SELECT x FROM (SELECT 
            c.id, 
            c.name, 
            row_to_json((SELECT y FROM (SELECT s.id, s.name) y)) AS js2
            ) x)) AS js1
    FROM p
    INNER JOIN s ON s.id = p.s_id
    INNER JOIN c ON c.s_id = p.s_id
    INNER JOIN cc ON c.id = cc.c_id AND p.c_id = cc.c_id
    GROUP BY p.c_id;
```

-HTH